# My batch variable saver keeps crashing

Tags: batch-file

This is what I have right now:

```
    :saveDetector
if exist %USERPROFILE%/Desktop/savefile.txt
goto :saveDetectorName
    else goto :name
:saveDetectorName
    if exist %USERPROFILE%/Desktop/savename.txt
    set /P c=Save detected. Would you like to load it?[Y/N]
        if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :saveloader
        if /T "%c%" EQU "N" goto :choice
        goto :saveDetectorName
:saveloader
    set /p save=<savefile.txt
    set /p name=<savename.txt
    goto :%save%
```

I've attempted to go and fix it by doing things like fix the variables in the text files, use several branches, and stuff like that. However, it keeps crashing. Anyone know why? (And yes, the text files only contain 1 line)

Comment: how it crashes?  Any errors printed?Does the `%save%` label exists?

Comment: yes, the %save% label does exist. When it crashes, it just closes the window, i didnt see any errors because it closed too fast for me to read anything that might of been there

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to do, not just dump the code. "batch variable saver" is quite unclear, and nor is it easy to infer from the code what you want to happen. Besides, you should paste *all* the code, not just the bit you think is relevant; you said the rest of it is fine, but readers need to be sure that's true, otherwise they can only guess. As for your latest comment, simply put a `pause` in it.

Comment: ok, i would go and put all of the code in however its over 800 lines and it might complain that the majority of what I wrote is code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if exist %USERPROFILE%/Desktop/savefile.txt
goto :saveDetectorName
    else goto :name
```

The syntax of an `if` statement is specific.

the command to be executed *must* be on the same line as the `if` or at least *start* on the same line if that command is a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of lines)

If an `else` clause is used then the `if-true` command must be parenthesised and the closing parenthesis, the `else` keyword and the opening parenthesis of the `if-false` command *must* all be on the same line and separated by spaces.

```
if exist %USERPROFILE%/Desktop/savefile.txt (
 goto saveDetectorName
) else (
 goto name
)
```

The colons are not required in a `goto`.

If you run thecode directly from the prompt, you will get a syntax-error report shown on-screen.

`/` is used to indicate a switch in windows. `\` is used to separate directories. Sometimes, **but not always** `/` will be translated.